# Optimize vector function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

this is a question about vector differentiation.

I had to optimize the following function: $(b-Ax)^T(b-Ax)$

$A$ is matrix, $x$ and h are column vectors

$$A(t) = A^T$$

I worked this out and computed the differential, $df$ which was:

$$h(t)A(t)Ax + x(t)A(t)Ah - b(t)Ah - h(t)A(t)b$$

My question is, how do I compute the derivative $D$ from this  and get a solution of the optimal $x$?

Comment: Where is $h$ in your objective? Also, you minimizing the objective with respect to what? $x$?

Comment: h = dx, i'm minimizing with respect to x

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is called least-squares minimization; you are trying to find

$$\min_x \|Ax-b\|^2,$$

whose KKT conditions are
$$A^TAx = A^Tb.$$

You derive these exactly the way you started, by differentiating the objective with respect to $x$:

$$dx^T A^TAx + x^TA^TAdx - b^TAdx - dx^TA^Tb$$

and noting that a scalar is equal to its transpose, so the above can be written as
$$dx \cdot 2(A^TAx - A^Tb).$$

Setting this derivative equal to zero for all infinitesimal motions $dx$ away from the critical point gives the condition above for optimality,
$$A^TAx = A^Tb.$$

If $A^TA$ is invertible then finding the minimizer $x$ is easy: $x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$. Otherwise, $A^Tb$ is always in the column space of $A^TA$, and you can find one of the (infinitely many) minimizers by e.g. using the QR decomposition of $A$.